# Output: In the same line

Tags: python

I have a script that creates a lot of output. Is there any way to create that in the same line?

For example

```
i, I = 0, 4
while i < I:
    i+=1
    print i
```

would print something like

```
1
2
3
4
```

How would I adjust it to print?

```
1 2 3 4
```

Obviously, the print commands have to be split up, otherwise the question is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `print i` to `print i,`:

```
i, I = 0, 4
while i < I:
    i+=1
    print i,
```

This prints it on the same line.